# Calculate percentage occurence in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I conducted a dietary analysis in a raptor species and I would like to calculate the percentage of occurence of the prey items in the three different stages of it's breeding cycle. I would like the occurence to be expressed a percentage of the sample size. As an example if the sample size is 135 and I get an occurence of Orthoptera 65. I would like to calculate the percentage: 65/135.

So far I have tried with the long version without succes. The result I am getting is not correct. Any help is highly recommended and sorry if this question is reposted.

The raw dataset is as it follows:

```
set.seed(123)
pellets_2014<-data.frame(
    Period = sample(c("Prebreeding","Breeding","Postbreedng"),12, replace=TRUE),
    Orthoptera = sample(0:10, 12,replace=TRUE),
    Coleoptera=sample(0:10,12,replace = TRUE),
    Mammalia=sample(0:10,12, replace=TRUE))
##I transform the file to long format
##Library all the necessary packages 
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(scales)
library(naniar)
pellets2014_long<-gather(pellets_2014,Categories, Count, c(Orthoptera,Coleoptera,Mammalia))

##I trasnform the zero values to NAs

pellets2014_NA<-pellets2014_long %>% replace_with_na(replace = list(Count = 0))

## Try to calculate the occurence 
Occurence2014<-pellets2014_NA %>% 
    group_by(Period,Categories) %>%
    summarise(n=n())

## I do get here but I don't get the right number of occurence and I am stuck how to get the right percentage
##If I try this: 

Occurence2014<-pellets2014_NA %>% 
    group_by(Period,Categories) %>%
    summarise(n=n())%>%mutate(Freq_n=n/sum(n)*100) 

##The above is also wrong because I need it to be divide by the sample size in each period (here is 4 samples per period, the overall sample size is 12)!
```

The output must be occurence and percentage of occurence for its prey category in each Period. As it is shown in the picture below

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETauQ.jpg)

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Hi @Sonny I need the percentage of occurence in Period~Categories like in the photo:https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbHqo.jpg

Comment: I would add `set.seed(123)` so we are all working from the same data

Comment: @Raoul just set it

Answer (score 0):

Is this close to what you're looking for?

```
Occurence2014 <- pellets2014_NA %>% 
  group_by(Period,Categories) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(
    freq = n / sum(n)
  )
```

Comment: Hi @Raoul Duke, thanks for your answer! Not really, I need the percentages to be explicit for every period. The percentage of pellets containing a given prey. Every row in the raw dataset represents 1 pellet.The denominator must be the sample size in each period.

Comment: I think the confusion is that there are more than one "Categories" per "Period".  Your example table lists just one of the "Categories" in Period == "Breeding", for instance.  It sounds like you want to group by Period and Categories but only show aggregate results by Period?

Comment: you are right, in each period the Categories can be more than 8! I do need the aggregated Percentage_Freq  of the Categories~Period. A good example is in the code below: 
```
Summary <- pellets2014 %>%
  group_by(Period, Categories) %>%
  summarise(Sum = sum(Count))
final <- recast(Summary, Categories~Period, id.var = c("Categories", "Period"))
final <- mutate(final, Prebreeding=Prebreeding/sum(Prebreeding)*100,  Postbreeding=Postbreeding/sum(Postbreeding)*100, Breeding=Breeding/sum(Breeding)*100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Occurence2014 <- pellets2014_NA %>% 
 group_by(Period) %>%
 mutate(period_sample_size = n()) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 group_by(Period,Categories,period_sample_size) %>%
 summarise(n=n())%>%
 mutate(Freq_n=n/period_sample_size*100)
```